# Android OS without Google Services?

Tags: uninstallation, operating-system

I have a Sony Xperia Z with version 4.1.2 running.

My question is about removing all of the Google baggage from the phone.

I have no Google account tied to my phone and would really like to get rid of all traces of Google from my phone for a few reasons:

- Battery performance: Google services ranks in the top 3 of what uses up my battery
- Privacy: I try to minimize what Google siphons from my phone with the exception of Google maps
- Less Dependency: I don't want to be dependent on one company for all my needs.

So are there any Android versions out there that are minimalistic and do not invade your privacy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most after-market ROMs ship without Google Apps by default. Take a look at e.g. [CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/), which is available for many devices. So if you can install custom ROMs, that's one way to go.

A different approach would be disabling all Google apps, or even remove them (on a rooted device). This might be a little more tricky as you would have to figure out all dependencies yourself.

Comment: Instructions for disabling apps (Android 4.0+) [here](http://www.droid-life.com/2013/02/06/how-to-disable-system-apps-in-android-beginners-guide/)

Comment: @loosebruce Not directly, but see: [Android without Google 6: Self-Experiment](http://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/android-without-google-6) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you need to consider if you have no Google account is what to do about your contacts and calendar.

Since you are not going to synchronize your phone contacts and calendar with Google, you need another solution.  A good option is to keep your data in Outlook on your computer and use [Akruto Sync](http://www.akruto.com/) to synchronize it with your phone.

Akruto Sync runs on your computer, allowing your Android phone to connect directly to your computer across the Internet, the same way it connects to Google, except that you are not sharing your information with anyone.  Your Outlook contacts and calendar are always up-to-date on your phone and they stay private.

Comment: So you're proposing sharing things with another big company (Microsoft) instead? They're not exactly more trustworthy than Google.